# ODBC Connection in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, odbc, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I need to create linked service with the ODBC connection in azure data factory to copy data from ODBC(Paris) to azure sql.

I have installed the ODBC driver in my SHIR , when I create linked service am getting error as
**ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  5: Access is denied. (Progress OpenEdge 11.7 Driver, C:\Users\X\Desktop\OpenEdge-11.7\pgoe27.dll).**

When i test the connection in my SHIR the test connection is successful.

What am I missing here? This is my first try and I do not find good resource on connection ODBC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which type of database do you want to copy is it MSSQL database or anything?

Comment: Progress database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of installing the driver on a folder inside a user profile, could you please install the driver on a folder on the root of the system drive like C:\OpenEdge-11.7\pgoe27.dll and make a right click on the folder that contains the driver, select properties, make a click on the Security tab, and provide Read access to "Everyone" on that folder and its content.